# Unreal Engine 4 - Collider component sweep issue

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have a 2D environment where an object falls (a trap) and a box collider component is moved with a timeline to follow the movement with SetRelativeLocation.

Since the trap is near a wall if I leave the Sweep option unchecked in some cases the character will stuck mid air between the trap and the wall.

[Sweep off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb1ZO.png)

If I turn on Sweep this will not happen and the character is pushed to ground correctly but since the collider "slows down" for some frames it seems to be in the middle of the sprite.

[Sweep on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBsLd.png)

Teleport option seems to have no effect on this behaviour.

Is there any way to have the sweep effect with the collider keeping his velocity and keeping the structure as it is with the collider moved by a timeline?

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I'm losing my head on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's 2D, have you tried blocking the input when your character collides? I would add a simple collider in front of your character and when it is overlapped, I'd limit the input in the direction your character goes, ie.:

1. Character collides right
2. MoveRight(float Scale): Clamp Scale to (-1.f, 0.f); AddMovementInput(...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kind solved it by using the "sweep on" version and launching character towards the floor so the sweeping collider reaches the character at the right moment. this works for now but I will surely try your suggestion for the next patch of the game.